# Find the primes $p$ such that $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}$ is a square number.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Find the primes $p$ such that $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}$ is a square number.

---

**Attempt:**

$p=2$ does not satisfy, $p=3$ satisfy. Now check for $p > 3$ (odd), and assume that 
$$ 2^{p-1}-1 = k^{2} p $$

Notice that $2 \equiv (-1) \bmod (3) \implies 2^{p-1} - 1\equiv (-1)^{p-1} - 1 \bmod (3) $. So $k^{2}$ must be divisible by $3$, and this implies $9 | k^{2}$.
$$ 2^{p-1}-1 = k^{2} p \implies 9 | 2^{p-1} - 1$$
$2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod(9)$.

By Euler's: $2^{6} \equiv 1 \bmod(9)$. Then let us check the primes
$$ p \equiv 1 \bmod(6) $$

Also notice that $4 | 2^{p-1} \implies 2^{p-1} - 1 \equiv 3 \bmod (4)$, and $k^{2}$ is not divisible by $2$ which means $k^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod(4)$, $pk^{2} \equiv p \bmod(4)$. So

$$ p \equiv 3 \bmod (4)$$

$p=7$ satisfy.